# Increase each integer by one return the Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to learning javascript and currently doing a free online mini-bootcamp before I start a more serious program. The mini-camp offered some exercises to practice what was taught during the video. I've watched the video multiple times trying to track down a clue as to what I'm doing wrong here and I've tried Googling the issue but I can't seem to turn anything up. I have very limited knowledge on how this all works, and I think I just need someone who knows what they're doing to explain it to me.

Here is the exercise, with the instructions commented just below:

```
function incrementByOne(arr) {
```

// arr is an array of integers
  // increase each integer by one
  // return the array

And here is my attempt at solving:

```
function incrementByOne(arr) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
    return (arr[i]); 
}
```

When I cross check my solution with the provided test it fails every time. I think the problem lies in my lack of understanding on how to properly return the array? I'm not sure, hopefully that's where you come in!

Comment: a `return` statement will stop execution... or in other words, your for loop is stopping on its first iteration

Comment: You are returning only one array element `arr[i]`, not the whole array `arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

The for loop will stop as soon as the condition evaluates to `false`. Because you want to loop over every array item, you have to compare `i` to the length of the array, which is `arr.length`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

The code inside the for loop is now executed for each element. Increment the `i`th element:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i]++; // increment it by one
}
```

Now, your array contains the updated values. Return a reference to the array:

```
function incrementByOne(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i]++; // increment it by one
  }
  return arr;
}
```

If you can create a new array:

```
function incrementByOne(arr) {
  return arr.map(item => item + 1);
}
// or:
var incrementByOne = arr => arr.map(i => i + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> // increase each integer by one
>
> // return the array

Just access each element and add it by 1.
Put back in the array and return finally

```
function incrementByOne(arr) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i]+1; // increase each integer by one
}
return arr; // Loop is done and return the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do

```js
function incrementByOne(arr) {
  // here you have to pass arr.length to denote how many elements you are traversing
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      // increment the element by 1
      arr[i] = arr[i] + 1; 
  }
  // return once the whole array has been updated
  return arr;
}


console.log(incrementByOne([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Added the changes in the comments, please take a look at them